# apache mod_rewrite redirection problem

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

ok i am having a problem with redirection on apache, i have a domain configured on my hosting account but the domain needs to be redirected to a folder. eg: / is root of server where the mysite.com answers /mysite is where the files are so i got this htaccess code to do the job:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mysite/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ mysite/index.php [L]
```

plus i made an index.php to redirect to mysite folder.
everything seems to be working good the only problem is i added a forum on /mysite/forums/
and for some reason instead of getting mysite.com/forums/ in the browser im getting mysite.com/mysite/forums/

could anyone help me solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would try writing the full address, so something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ http://www.site.com/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i got what was wrong and i thank everyone that had a look at it.

**Solution:**
Change last line

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ mysite/index.php [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ mysite/$1 [L]
```

so it answer to anything coming from that folder not just the index.php :)